# How to properly use get_sensor?

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have some code which uses get_sensor to get a laser sensor, however when I want to use two of this model, they get muddled up as I can't reference the full model name.

sensors::SensorPtr model_sensor;

model_sensor = sensors::get_sensor("laser"); // this is fine when there's only one laser sensor

I want to get something like:

model_sensor = sensors::get_sensor("my_model::hoyoko::link::laser"); but I'm confident this is wrong as gazebo crashes with this new code.

I have the get_sensor refference : http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/1.4.0/group__gazebo__sensors.html   (Ctrl f "get_sensor" to find the relevant part)

But I don't fully understand what they mean by " This name should be fully scoped. This means _name = world_name::model_name::link_name::sensor_name."

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15221/how-to-properly-use-get_sensor?/) by [Robot_sim_person](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2938/robot_sim_person/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It turns out you can either use just the sensor_name for the string, or the whole thing. But nothing in between (i.e. "model_name::link_name::sensor_name" is not acceptable.

An easy way to get an example of this is to print GetScopedName() on the terminal
( "model_sensor->GetScopedName()" ) .

---

Originally posted by [Robot_sim_person](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2938/robot_sim_person/) with karma: 3 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-17**:
Thanks for posting your solution. I'm curious, what do you mean by "the whole thing" if it's not the scoped name? Maybe this is a bug in Gazebo, it shouldn't crash with a bad string.

**Comment by [Robot_sim_person](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2938/robot_sim_person/) on 2017-01-18**:
If I try to find the sensor without the world name, i.e:

sensorLocation = /*"default::" +*/ this->model->GetName() + "::hokuyo::link::laser";
the get_sensor function will crash.

But it will work fine if I either include all the names, or just the sensor name. The whole thing is:

sensorLocation = "default::" + this->model->GetName() + "::hokuyo::link::laser";

Just the sensor name is:

sensorLocation = "laser";

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-18**:
Thanks for the clarification